# grunt copy task is misbehaving

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

**Update**

Part of the problem is that `front/styles` contains both css and scss files. I only want to copy css files.

**Original**

So the `copy` task from `grunt-contrib-copy` should be doing one thing. Copying all the `*.css` files from `front/styles` and move them to `front/build/styles`

```
copy: {
  css: {
    files: {
      src: ['front/styles/*.css'],
      dest: 'front/build/styles/',
      filter: 'isFile'
    }
  }
},
```

I run `grunt copy` and it creates a folder called `dest` in the same level as the `front` folder. I go in to `front/build/styles` and nothing is there. This is a relatively easy task to config and have done so in the past but this is baffling to me.

What am I overlooking in the config?

Comment: Try src: ['front/styles/*']

Comment: Ahh but there are scss files in there. Could solve by splitting styles in to css and scss but would really like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
copy: {
  css: {
    files: {
      cwd: 'front/styles/',
      src: '*.css',
      dest: 'front/build/styles/',
      filter: 'isFile'
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: This configuration now creates two folders `dest` like before and `cwd` which is new as the same level as the `front` folder. Both empty. Why is it ignoring the values I'm input, taking the task config params and creating them as empty directories?

Comment: Silly question, but are you running compass before the copy task or after? Maybe the .css files do not exist yet in the part of the process? Can we see more of the grunt file?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

```
copy: {
  css: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        src: 'front/styles/*.css',
        dest: 'front/build/styles/'
      }
    ]
  }
},
```